# How to change uiview color when user touches the screen

Tags: ipad

I am creating an ipad app and I have a button that can create a rectangle with red fill and blue border. I want to change the border color when i touch the created rectangle. which statement should i use? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yourRect and borderColor are iVars. You have to write method changeBorderColor for logic of changing color ever time the rectangle is touched.

```
- (void) init
{
  yourRect = CGRectMake(100,100, 200,200);
  borderColor = [UIColor blueColor];

  UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;     
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap:];
    [singleTap release];
}

-(void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint tapLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:shareView];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(yourRect, tapLocation))
    {
        borderColor = [self changeBorderColor]; //Change color
    }
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
{   
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, yourRect);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, borderColor.CGColor);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, yourRect);
}
```